# Javascript round decimal value in object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to JavaScript and facing issue with rounding decimal number. I have a object with 'n' no of key value pairs. Key value pairs can be string or number or null. I want to just target number key value pair and round the number value with 2 decimal places. Eg. If i have value as `1.798` i want to round it to `1.80`. i have no idea how many key value pair will be present in my object just want to target number value and replace it.

I tried foreach but later found it works on array type

```
var obj = {
    name: 'abc',
    term1: 0,
    term2: 1.798,
    term3: 1.9999,
    term4: 0,
    term5: null,
    term6: 'xyz'
};


// Expected output

var obj = {
    name: 'abc',
    term1: 0,
    term2: 1.80,
    term3: 2.00,
    term4: 0,
    term5: null,
    term6: 'xyz'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can not have the trailing zeros since numbers do not have significant digits. You can make it a string and it would maintain the zeros.

```js
var obj = {
    name: 'abc',
    term1: 0,
    term2: 1.798,
    term3: 1.9999,
    term4: 0,
    term5: null,
    term6: 'xyz'
};

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if(typeof value === 'number') {
    // obj[key] = value.toFixed(2) // 1.9999 -> "2.00"
    obj[key] = +value.toFixed(2) // 1.9999 -> 2
  }
})

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `typeof` to identify numbers and `.toFixed(n)` to round to n places (and return as a string, otherwise trailing 0s are lost)

```
var obj = {
    name: 'abc',
    term1: 0,
    term2: 1.798,
    term3: 1.9999,
    term4: 0,
    term5: null,
    term6: 'xyz',
};
for(propertyName in obj){
    if(typeof obj[propertyName] === 'number'){
        obj[propertyName] = obj[propertyName].toFixed(2);
    }
}
console.log(obj) //  Object { name: "abc", term1: "0.00", term2: "1.80", term3: "2.00", term4: "0.00", term5: null, term6: "xyz" }
```

Comment: Probably should also use `parseInt()` on the corresponding result. The problem's expected output has them formatted as numbers but yeah this is a solid solution.

Comment: If you want as number after `.toFixed()` then it looks like `+(12.128.toFixed(2))` which returns `12.13` in typeof `number`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys(obj)` to loop over the keys and make decisions. Here's a working solution for your problem:

```
var obj = {

name: 'abc', term1: 0, term2: 1.798, term3: 1.9999, term4: 0, term5: null, term6: 'xyz'

};

for(var key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    if(typeof obj[key] === 'number' && obj[key] !== 0) {
    obj[key] = (Math.round(obj[key] * 100)) / 100;
  }
}
```

Fiddle to work in: https://jsfiddle.net/x4otdeca/

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result use for in to llop object

1. iterate object using for in
2. Check if it is null or string and use toFixed(2) to round the decimal values

   ```js
   var obj = {
     name: 'abc', 
     term1: 0, 
     term2: 1.798, 
     term3: 1.9999, 
     term4: 0, 
     term5: null, 
     term6: 'xyz'
   };

   for( let key in obj){
      obj[key] = !obj[key] || isNaN(obj[key])? obj[key] : obj[key].toFixed(2)
   }

   console.log(obj)
   ```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/dybNwEW?editors=1010